# Несколько json_encode в ajax запросе

Tags: php, javascript

Нужно вывести содержимое двух массивов с помощью ajax. появляется ошибка в js при распарсивании массива Unexpected token { in JSON at position 19

```
$.ajax({
  url: "1.php",
  type:"POST",
  success: function(data){
       data=JSON.parse(data);
       console.log( "Прибыли данные: ", data );
  }
});

<?php
    $arr1=array("a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3);
    echo json_encode($arr1);
    $arr2=array("foo"=>132,"bar"=>456,4);
    echo json_encode($arr2);    
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что как только вы один раз написали `echo`, всё — поезд ушёл. Ушёл в город ajax на станцию success (ну или complete).
Второе `echo` уже едет в белебердовку.

Чтобы отправить оба, нужно их положить в отдельную переменную:

```
$data = ['arr1' =>  $arr1, 'arr2' => $arr2];
```

и затем это всё отправить:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```